Migration from numpy.distutils
In Python 3.12 they (finally) turned off support for numpy.distutils.  Instead of being lazy and using an older version, I am trying to migrate an old package of mine from numpy.distutils to whatever will work without pain.
I was considering using setuptools but cannot find the equivalent function for
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration

Can anyone help me here or share their migration experience from numpy.distutils?
